# I am getting a strange result for an expression with ternary operator

Tags: javascript

I am getting a strange value for the following expression, while I trying to change the k code when the shift key pressed in keyUp event.

var k = 39 - (e.shiftKey) ? 2 : 0;
Result: 2

But, When it is used by enclosing brackets, it is working fine

var k = 39 - ((e.shiftKey) ? 2 : 0);
Result: 37

Please advise, what is the root cause for this, why the first expression is not at all considering the value 39. Need your help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) ... `-` sits a 13, `?:` sits at 4 ... so, yeah, operator precedence is the reason for this expected result

Comment: Two words: operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Your first expression subtracts e.shiftKey from 39 and evaluates whether the result is true or false.  The value is a nonzero value, and therefore evaluates to `true` when cast as boolean.  Therefore, the result is 2, since 2 is the result if the expression is true.

Your second expression evaluates whether e.shiftKey is true or false.  The value is also nonzero, so it is also true.  The result is therefore 2, which *then* gets subtracted from 39, leaving 37.

Your statements are equivalent to these (the parents in the first one are unnecessary; I've just put them in for clarity):

```
var k = (39 - e.shiftKey) ? 2 : 0;

var k = 39 - (e.shiftKey ? 2 : 0);
```

Put into if statements they look like this:

```
if (39 - e.shiftKey == true) k = 2;

if (e.shiftKey == true) k = 39 - 2;
```

So, as the commenters above are saying, it's a matter of operator precedence.  Parentheses always come first, since they're used to override precedence.  Then logical NOT (!), then exponents, then multiplication/division, then addition/subtraction, then &&, then ||, then ternary operators.  Those are just the basics; there are quite a few others in there.  Have a look at the doc that Jaromanda X linked.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's been so long, I logged into StackOverflow. That's the reason, I am unable to reply to your solution. Anyways,  Thank you again.

Comment: @Masvi You're welcome. Feel free to accept it as the answer if you find that it answered your question.